# Unable to install 'mysql-connector-python' in a Docker Container

Tags: python, docker, pip, mysql-connector-python

I faceing some issues while installing mysql-connector-python via pip in a Docker container.

I tried so mutch and searched in google for some help for almost the whole day :O
May the stackoverflow community can help me out now

My Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

CMD [ "python", "./run.py" ]
```

the requirements.txt:

```
Flask==1.1.1
markdown==3.1.1
mysql-connector-python==8.0.17
```

[image: project structure]

In the image you can see where my different files are located. As soon as I now try to import the mysql package in the **init**.py with `import mysql.connector`I get following error:

```
[...]/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
import mysql.connector
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql'
```

EDIT: my **init**.py:

```
import markdown
import os
import mysql.connector

from flask import Flask
from flask import request, jsonify

#Create an instance of Flask
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")

def index():
    """Present some API documentation"""

    # Open the README file
    with open(os.path.dirname(app.root_path) + '/README.md', 'r') as markdown_file:

        #Read content
        content = markdown_file.read()

        #Convert to HTML
        return markdown.markdown(content)

@app.route("/healthinsurances", methods=['GET','POST'])
def healthinsurances():
    if (request.method == 'GET'):
        cnx = connection.MySQLConnection(user='usr', password='pwd', host='host', database='db')
        cnx.close()
        return jsonify({'some': 'json'})
    else:
        some_json = request.get_json()
        return jsonify({'you sent': some_json}), 201
```

I further listed the listed the pip install in the container which are:

```
$ docker exec 7d5267a06dcc8c0f1d3a421c79f20c559fddf8ed65ada329e6f71ce69ddb0567 pip list
Package      Version
------------ -------
Click        7.0    
Flask        1.1.1  
itsdangerous 1.1.0  
Jinja2       2.10.3 
Markdown     3.1.1  
MarkupSafe   1.1.1  
pip          19.2.3 
setuptools   41.2.0 
Werkzeug     0.16.0 
wheel        0.33.6
```

So my problem is, that I see that the package is obviously not installed. But I have no idea why??!

May you can help me out. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: are you using docker-compose?

Comment: yes i use `docker-compose up`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to post your __init__ and run code. I set up the same docker as you and ran it with `-it` and was able to import mysql.connector without issues. Noticed there's differences in our pip list though.

Dockerfile:

```sh
FROM python:3

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

CMD [ "/bin/bash" ]
```

Req.txt:

```sh
Flask==1.1.1
markdown==3.1.1
mysql-connector-python==8.0.17
```

Bash output:

```sh
zhiyong@----:~/projects/stack_overflow$ docker run -it stackoverflow
root@fd9bad5fc107:/usr/src/app# ls
Dockerfile  requirements.txt  run.py
root@fd9bad5fc107:/usr/src/app# python
Python 3.7.4 (default, Sep 12 2019, 15:40:15) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import mysql.connector
root@fd9bad5fc107:/usr/src/app# pip list
Package                Version
---------------------- -------
Click                  7.0    
Flask                  1.1.1  
itsdangerous           1.1.0  
Jinja2                 2.10.3 
Markdown               3.1.1  
MarkupSafe             1.1.1  
mysql-connector-python 8.0.17 
pip                    19.2.3 
protobuf               3.10.0 
setuptools             41.2.0 
six                    1.12.0 
Werkzeug               0.16.0 
wheel                  0.33.6
```

Comment: Well, thats curious. I edited my questiona and attached the __init__.py

Comment: Maybe because I use `docker-compose up` instead of `docker run`.